# Refrence type as a member in Struct what happen?

Tags: c#

When a struct contains a reference type as a member, then how the default constructor of the member invoked explicitly..

and what happens when default constructor is not invoked.

pls ans with example

eg

```
class myClass 
{
   int slNo;
   string name;

   public myClass(int a, string nam)
   {
      slNo = a;
      name = nam;  

   } 

}

struct myStruct 

{
  myClass obj = new myClass();
  // Error : Cannot have instance field initializers in struct...
  .....   
}
```

> // Error : Cannot have instance field initializers in struct...
>
> so want to know how it is invoked explicitly....

Comment: pls ask with example

Comment: If you have a reference type as the member of a struct, then all that struct actually contains is some space for a pointer.

Comment: The answer is: "It isn't"

Comment: Reference types are not initialized in structs, check [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4(v=vs.90).aspx), so you will not be able to do like this:
`struct str
{
public myClass cls;
};
struct1 var1;
do something with var1 ; compiler will show error here`
you either should assign all variable my hands, like:
`struct str
{
public myClass cls;
};
str var1;var1.cls = new myClass();`
or you can use parametric constructors like:
`struct str
{
public myClass cls;
public str(myClass v)
{
this.cls = v;
}
};
str var1 = new str(new myClass());`

Answer (score 2):

Like any other time, the default value for a reference type is `null`.  This isn't C++ and members are not default constructed. They are initialized with `default(T)`.